# ng-messages affecting all fields on form in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set up a ng-message to affect all fields in a form. If I have 3 fields (Name, Age, Gender) can I have one ng-message show if any of them is invalid?

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="ctrl.Name" required />
   <input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="ctrl.Age" required />
   <input type="text" name="Gender" ng-model="ctrl.Gender" required />
   *<div ng-messages="myForm.all.$error">*
      <div ng-message="required">Must Fill all Fields</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

i.e. Is there something I could use instead of *all*

Comment: Maybe `myForm.$error`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i tried that. no results. but please don't guess.